# How to use POST method with Asp.Net Master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and on the other asp.net form I need to call a method to .ashx file something as shown below:

As I am having problem with the buttons as whatever the button I click its Posting back the content which I don't want to.

```
 <form id="Form1" action="Upload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="fileupload" style="border: thin solid #666666; width: 600px; height: 520px;
        z-index: 1; left: 18px; top: 22px; position: absolute; overflow: auto;">
        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
            <label class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="start">
                Start upload</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancel">
                Cancel upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="delete">
                Delete all files</button>
            <div class="fileupload-progressbar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-content" style="border-style: none">
            <table class="files">
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

which is not possible as I have a content page.

So how do I do that within the content of the asp.net form which is based on the masterpage.

Comment: "master page and on the other form"? What are you trying to do? You are probably trying to do something, and the way you are going about it is completely wrong when it comes to asp.net and master pages

Comment: Yes I am just trying to show the form which I presently have and on that form I have a post method.And I am working with masterpages so how do I do with masterpages is my doubt!

Comment: I need to post the data to upload.ashx file from the content place holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have server side form tag posting to a different page. Server side form control is designed to post-back to self (it ignores the action attribute) - that's why you see your page getting posted to (content) page. Master page is not really a page but rather a template/layout - content page denotes the actual page (master page is really a control whose control tree get merged into the content page tree).

You can also have [cross-page posting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx) using server side button controls.

However, I believe for whatever you are trying to achieve, you need creating a **separate** html form tag. For example,

```
...

<!-- server side form - do not touch -->
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
... 
</form>

...

<!-- you can have multiple html form tags but you cannot use server controls -->
<form action="Upload.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply that link is exactly what I am looking now!